# Running web job gives ArgumentNullException on start

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I'm developing an Azure webjob using .NET Framework but when I'll run this localy, I've this exception after the startup.

> **`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException`:** The listener for function *`[Name of function]`* was unable to start.
>
> Inner exception:
>
> `ArgumentNullException`: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: `connectionString`

This is the code inside the `Program` class of the web job.

```csharp
static void Main()
{
    HostBuilder builder = new HostBuilder();

    builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
    {
        b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
        b.AddTimers();
    });

    using (IHost host = builder.Build())
    {
        host.Run(); // <-- error happens on this line
    }
}
```

Inside the `App.config` I've added next two connection strings:

```xml
<add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[Name];AccountKey=[Key]" />
<add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[Name];AccountKey=[Key]" />
```

With `[Name]` and `[Key]` as the account name en key from a live environment.

Also when I change the connection strings to `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`, I'm getting the same exception.

How could I solve this?

Comment: is it a .net core console project or .net framework console project?

Comment: I'm using .NET Framework.

Comment: Please see the updated answer below.

Comment: @IvanYang sorry I didn't find the time to check it. I'll check it before Friday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

If you're using Azure WebJobs SDK of version 3.x with .NET Framework, there is an issue: [Version 3.x is incompatible with .NET Framework and `PackageReference`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2186).

So there're several ways as workaround:

1. Directly use the [Azure WebJobs template from Visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs#create), it's based on `.net framework`.
2. You can add an `appsettings.json` file (**Note**: right click the file → select Properties → then set *"Copy to Output Directory"* to *"Copy if newer"*) to the .NET Framework project, it will work(based on 1, it will throw errors, but it can work). The JSON file looks like below:

   ```
   {
       "AzureWebJobsStorage": "{storage connection string}"
   }
   ```
3. The best solution is to use .NET Core with WebJobs SDK of version 3.x.

---

**Original answer:**

If you're using WebJob SDK version 3.x, I suggest you should create a **.NET Core console project** instead of **.NET Framework console project**, then you should follow this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started).

First, create a [.NET Core console app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started#create-a-project). And install all the necessary packages mentioned in the official doc.

Your program.cs:

```
static void Main()
{
    HostBuilder builder = new HostBuilder();

    builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
    {
        b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
        b.AddAzureStorage();
        b.AddTimers();
    });

    using (IHost host = builder.Build())
    {
        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Then create a function, please refer to [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started#create-a-function).

Then add an `appsettings.json` file (**Note**: right click the file → select Properties → then set *"Copy to Output Directory"* to *"Copy if newer"*), add the `AzureWebJobsStorage` inside it:

```
{
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "{storage connection string}"
}
```

Please let me know if you still have more issues about that.